# Why I got HibernateProxy obj at run mode, but get domain in debug mode. How does that happened

Tags: java, hibernate

I have domain Object like

```
public class Person{
  private String name ;
  private Integer age;
}
```

I have DAO criteria like

```
{
  Criteria c = sesseion.createCriteria(Person.class);
  c.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("age"))));
  List<Object> rows = c.list();
  for(Object obj:rows){
     if ((obj != null) && (obj instanceof HibernateProxy))
    {
      doSomething...
    }
  }
}
```

When I run it in Run mode, it works, but when I set debug point at "if" condition line, it shows the obj I get is Person class, not HibernateProxy. Then it failed in debug mode.

Why one object is appearing as different instance form with run mode and debug mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate loads the proxies of your classes initially (based on the loading strategy) and when you call some method on that proxy, it actually loads the original object. While in debug mode, eclipse uses introspection (calls the fields or setters or getters).

In your case `toString()` on proxy gets called, which internally uses other fields of that class, hence, hibernate loads the original object.

Comment: Nice and correct explanation, except: Eclipse is never calling setters or getters (unless you ask it to do so in expression / display view) - it uses field introspection and toString() only.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke, Good point, I spoke in general, just like you said, if you want to inspect or watch, it will call the methods.